# MySQL group_concat and concat

Tags: mysql

I have these data on MySQL table `cart`.

[image]

I would like to run a query that would output like this:

`Advance Technique Conditioner (2), Advance Technique Gel (1)`

So I was doing a `group_concat` query and was trying queries to output my desired output. This is the query that outputted the nearest to the desired:

`select concat(group_concat(product separator ', '), group_concat(quantity separator ', ')) as 'prod' from cart where debt_no='0000001'`

But as expected, it outputted like this : `Advance Technique Conditioner, Advance Technique Gel2, 1`

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CONCAT()` should be inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(product, ' (', CAST(quantity AS CHAR(15)), ')') SEPARATOR ', ')
```

remember that the default length of `GROUP_CONCAT()` is 1024. So if you want to change the limit execute the following line,

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val; -- val is the new length
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this and I was wondering why the output is `[BLOB - 6OB]`. So that's why. I'm having an error when I try to execute the said line.

Comment: oh then you should convert `quantity` first since it's a number. I'll update the answer

Comment: The updated query is outputting fine now! Thanks a lot! But I'm still having errors when executing this `SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = 5000;`

Comment: choose one, `SET GLOBAL` or `SET SESSION`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and for your patience! :D

Comment: why did you use `quantity AS CHAR(15)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(product, ' (', quantity, ')') SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the `concat()` first, then the `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(concat(product, ' (', quantity, ')') separator ', ') as prod
from cart where debt_no='0000001'
```